# How to maintain logged in user in Vue

Tags: javascript, php, session, vue.js

I am making an app that need user to be logged into the app. I used to make that solutions via js and php and mysql, however it is first time i am trying it using Vue.

I used to do it this way on the server side:

```
if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] > 0 ) { 
   require_once("page.php");
} else {
   require_once("login.php");
}
```

But since i am using Vue, how can i achieve same results that different pages/components load depending on user is logged in and authorized or not?
And redirect user to page that he has permission to enter?
Kalreg.

Comment: This depends a lot of how your Vue app is setup, what your using for routing in Vue etc... If you're using Vue Router (https://router.vuejs.org/en/) you can use navigation guards (https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to prevent users from accessing certain pages depending on  whether they are logged in. Need more information about what you're trying to achieve, but if this sounds like what you're trying to do I can post some examples of how I use Vue Router to handle authentication in my apps.

Comment: I use Vue Router indeed, so any secure idea would be great. I imagine that each try of downloading any data from server is secured server side - if user has session variable with user_id set then it returns data otherwise return error, however i can secure data from downloading by unauthorized user, not components - cause any user can change return value from server and see how components look if they were logged in. Anyways please prowide your examples - it would be more than appreciated